# Variables en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

mi pregunta es mas que nada teorica. Basicamente programo en c++ y empeze a ver algo de python el problema es que no entiendo cuando se "elimina" la variable en python. Ejemplo

codigo en c++

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int valor=1;
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        int valor=2;
        cout<<valor<<endl;
    }
    cout<<valor<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

eso da como resultado en consola 1 y 2

en cambio en python el codigo

```
valor=1
for k in range(1):
    valor = 2
print(valor)
```

Da como resultado 2. Yo se que la memoria estatica en c++ se borra cuando se cierra la llave del for pero en python no se como funciona. Si alguien me aclara como es que funciona la memoria en esos caso se lo agradeceria. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En C++ una variable declarada dentro de un ciclo, es local a ese loop. En Python no existe un alcance privado para los ciclos. Cualquier variable o bien tiene un alcance local dentro de una función o bien global a nivel de un módulo. En este ejemplo:

```
valor=1
for k in range(1):
    valor = 2
```

En realidad solo has definido una única variable global `valor` para todo el código. Para ser estrictos con el lenguaje, con `valor=1` has creado un objeto del tipo `<class 'int'>` con el valor `1` y lo has bautizado con el nombre `valor`, luego con `valor = 2` has creado otro objeto distinto al anterior, también del tipo `<class 'int'>` pero con el valor `2` y has "reutilizado" el nombre `valor` para nombrarlo. Importante mencionar la existencia en Python del "Garbage collector" un proceso que corre en paralelo con tu Script y se encarga de ir liberando los objetos en memoria cuyas referencias ya no son válidas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion. Para redondear la idea le pregunto, En ese momento python estaria guardando dos objetos diferentes en memoria y yo estaria invocando el valor del ultimo. Pero de ser asi estariamos "desperdiciando" memoria porque el segundo objeto va a quedar sin acceso.
 Perdon por la ignoracia esto de que no haya punteros y ocurran cosas "abajo" de la alfombra me tiene intrigado.

Comment: @t.t, es una buena pregunta.  En python y muchos otros lenguajes, existe un elemento muy importante que es el "Garbage Collector", un motor que se encarga de revisar los objetos huérfanos (que no están referenciados por ninguna variable activa) e ir liberando la memoria

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho también quisiera añadir que si bien el "Garbage Collector" ayuda a liberar memoria hay que tener en cuenta las [fugas de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria) *-Memory Leaks-* que pueden llegar a ocurrir también [Python: garbage collection fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617001/python-garbage-collection-fails) algo que también me ha dado más de un dolor de cabeza en **Lua**

Answer (score 2):

El comportamiento que se describe en la pregunta es porque el alcance de las variables en **Python**, son globales cuando están fuera de una función.

En este caso concreto el bucle `for` al no ser una función toma la variable `valor` como global

```
valor = 1
for k in range(1):
    valor = 2
    print(valor)

print(valor)
# Se imprime:
# 2 correspondiente al bucle for
# 2 fuera del bucle for
```

Pero si el citado bucle estuviera dentro de una función `_valor()` la variable `valor` sería tratada como local dentro de dicha función

```
valor = 1
def _valor():
  for k in range(1):
    valor = 2
    print(valor)

_valor()
print(valor)
# Se imprime:
# 2 correspondiente al bucle for
# 1 fuera del bucle for
```

No obstante es posible acceder a las variables globales dentro de una función con la palabra reservada `global`

```
valor = 1
def _valor():
  global valor
  for k in range(1):
    valor = 2
    print(valor)

_valor()
print(valor)
# Se imprime:
# 2 correspondiente al bucle for
# 2 fuera del bucle for
```

Asimismo si la variable `valor` estuviera sólo en una función se observaría el mismo comportamiento, es decir su alcance local dentro de la función es como si fuera `global` pero sólo en esa función:

```
def _valor():
  valor = 1
  for k in range(1):
    valor = 2
    print(valor)
  print(valor)

_valor()
# Se imprime:
# 2 correspondiente al bucle for
# 2 fuera del bucle for
```

Puede parecer algo raro, pero simplifica mucho código desde mi experiencia. Por ejemplo cuando uso **Lua** si las variables no se les coloca la palabra reservada `local` son declaradas como `globales` indistintamente si están dentro o no de una función, así como dentro de una clase u objeto o una tabla o un array.

Aquí a mi parecer **Python** resuelve lo anterior de forma elegante porque sólo se emplea `global` para acceder cuando así se requiera a variables ajenas a la función en cuestión, evitándose accidentalmente sobreescribir variables entre funciones.