# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el valor de una variable para que siempre este disponible?

Tags: python

El programa en cuestión consiste en hacer el programa de un banco, en el que se suma dinero al balance que ya tengas, puedas retirar dinero, y puedas consultar el saldo, suponiendo que retiras dinero, debería guardarse el numero de dinero disponible, y luego poder ser consultado con la tercera opción, pero no se guardan los datos de las variables (quiero que solo se pueda salir al presionar el número 4 en el menú).

```
    def run():
    for i in range(100):
        menu = """
        Hola, bienvenido al programa de tu banco favorito
        Selecciona alguna opcion
        [1]Ingresar dinero
        [2]Retirar Dinero
        [3]Ver balance
        [4]Cerrar el menú    
        """
        balance = None
        select = int(input("Selecciona una opción: "))
        if select == 1:
            dinero = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de dinero que quieres depositar: "))
            balance = + dinero
            return balance

        elif select == 2:
            egreso = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de dinero que quieres retirar: "))
            balance = - egreso

        elif select == 3:
            balancestr = str(balance)
            print("Actualmente tienes $" + balancestr + " En tu cuenta de banco.")

        elif select == 4:
            print("Espero hayas podido concluir tus cuentas con exito, hasta pronto! ")
        
        else:
            print("Ingresa una opcion valida")
            print(balance)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Por qué no mejor inicias balance en 0? Otra cosa, nota que estás usando un for establecido a 100 repeticiones, es decir, a la 101ª iteración el ciclo se rompe. Si tu idea es que te quedes ahí indefinidamente deberías usar un `while true:` en su lugar, y en la opción que quieras salir del ciclo añade un `break`. Puedes revisar esta pregunta para el problema con la variable. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248520/variables-en-python/248532?r=SearchResults#248532. Que gracioso. Mientras escribía alguien también te respondió y dijo algo de lo que te mencionaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modificando un poco tu codigo:

```
   def run():
        balance = 0
        while(True):
            print("""
            Hola, bienvenido al programa de tu banco favorito
            Selecciona alguna opcion
            [1]Ingresar dinero
            [2]Retirar Dinero
            [3]Ver balance
            [4]Cerrar el menú    
            """)
            select = int(input("Selecciona una opción: "))
            if select == 1:
                dinero = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de dinero que quieres depositar: "))
                balance = balance + dinero
        
            elif select == 2:
                egreso = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de dinero que quieres retirar: "))
                balance = balance - egreso
        
            elif select == 3:
                balancestr = str(balance)
                print("Actualmente tienes $" + balancestr + " En tu cuenta de banco.")
        
            elif select == 4:
                print("Espero hayas podido concluir tus cuentas con exito, hasta pronto! ")
                break
            
            else:
                print("Ingresa una opcion valida")
                print(balance)
            
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        run()
```

Bueno agregue `balance = 0` adentro de la funcion y antes del while infinito para que me sirva como un acumulador, vi tu error en python no se pone `balance = + dinero` ya que teoria eso no esta en python, colocalo `balance = balance + dinero` y asi podras obtener el acumulado actualizado..

Ademas agrege un `break;` en la seleccion 4  para que me salga del bucle infinito y asi terminar el programa.

Comment: Recuerden que en Python no es necesario el uso de `;`. Queda a su criterio usar o no.